# (Ruby on Rails) How To Display An Alert Icon If A Variable Number Is Too High In A Partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following code in a partial which is used for displaying all the users I have to an admin account:

```
<li>
  <%= link_to user.name, user %>
    | <%= pluralize(user.how_many_new_posts?, "unedited post") %> 
  <% if current_user.admin? && !current_user?(user) %>
    | <%= link_to "delete", user, method: :delete,
                                  data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
  <% end %>
</li>
```

I want the line "<%= pluralize(user.how_many_new_posts?, "unedited post") %>" to generate an alert icon next to the text if the result of user.how_many_new_posts? is higher than a certain number (say 4 for example).

I feel like this will require an integration of Ruby code & CSS but I'm not very strong with either so I was hoping someone on here could shed some light on how to progress.

Answer (score 0):

You already gave yourself the answer, just check if the result of user.how_many_new_posts? is higher than 4, if yes, then the icon will be there:

```
<%= pluralize(user.how_many_new_posts?, "unedited post") %> 
<% if user.how_many_new_posts? > 4 %>
<img src="alert_icon">
<% end %>
```